# Image Magick Unwanted Colour Change

Tags: android, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Im resizing an icon using image magick. The original icon is grey but when i resize it using this command: convert -resize 50.0% -unsharp 0x1 the smaller icons that are produced are black. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks
David